# Pig 10 filter chararray by is not null doesn't work

Tags: filter, apache-pig

I'm new to pig and I'm playing around with it and came to a roadblock.

Imagine I have the following:

```
dump test;

(1,2014-04-08 12:09:23.0)
(2,2014-04-08 12:09:23.0)
(3,null)
(4,null)
```

I want to filter "test" to remove the null values so I would do something like this:

```
filter_test = filter test by test.column2 is not null;
```

To give me something like this:

```
(1,2014-04-08 12:09:23.0)
(2,2014-04-08 12:09:23.0)
```

But it returns the same thing. It doesn't remove the null rows.

I'm using Pig 10 and the date column is of type chararray.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column2 doesn't have null value its a chararray. please see the examples for real null value and null as chararray.

**Example1: null as chararray**
**input.txt**

```
1,2014-04-08 12:09:23.0
2,2014-04-08 12:09:23.0
3,null
4,null
```

**Pig:**

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (f1:int,f2:chararray);
B = FILTER A BY f2!='null';
DUMP B;
```

**Output:**

```
(1,2014-04-08 12:09:23.0)
(2,2014-04-08 12:09:23.0)
```

**Example2: Real null value**
**input.txt**

```
1,2014-04-08 12:09:23.0
2,2014-04-08 12:09:23.0
3,
4,
```

**Pig:**

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (f1:int,f2:chararray);
B = FILTER A BY f2 is not null;
DUMP B;
```

**Output:**

```
(1,2014-04-08 12:09:23.0)
(2,2014-04-08 12:09:23.0)
```

Comment: Awesome! It worked! I saw that NULL would be an empty bag/tuple and I honestly thought I tried your way. I guess I didn't. Thanks.